# Occasionally 'No implementation found for native .... ' error happens

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Presumably, this is not the case has disscussed here before.

We are using CAN functionalities implemented using JNI.

I just found this error yesterday. Very rarely, 'No implementation found for native' error happens when I try to load the CAN library and run a function in it.

Once I reboot the system, the error is gone and works again.

The JNI code is written in C, not C++.

Any help will be appreciated!!!!

## Error Log :

```
D/dalvikvm( 1514): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libFlexCAN.so 0x41945b10, skipping init
W/dalvikvm( 1514): No implementation found for native Lcommunication/flexcan/core/Connection;.na_openPort:(I)I
E/Exception( 1514): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: communication.flexcan.core.Connection.na_openPort:(I)I
E/Exception( 1514):  at communication.flexcan.core.Connection.na_openPort(Native Method)
E/Exception( 1514):  at communication.flexcan.core.Connection.access$0(Connection.java:117)
E/Exception( 1514):  at communication.flexcan.core.Connection$ReceiveThread.run(Connection.java:147)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the library using NDK before using the library. After building, it will generate .so files which can be used. Details: https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: Thanks berserk. But I already build the library and have used it without the error. The error only occurs one out of hundred reboots. It's very strange.

Comment: @YongJunChang Oh. Is it at a particular case or random? I mean some functions may not be working.

Comment: @ berserk I can say that it's a random case. As you can see in the error log, 'libFlexCAN.so' has been successfully loaded. But 'No implementation found for native' error happens. I know it can happen in the name mangling case in C++. But the libFlexCAN is written C, and it can be run in most of times.

Comment: @YongJunChang Try rebuilding lib man. I am not sure why you getting error.